# Does spring @Scheduled annotation use system's cron? (e.g. ubuntu cron) or spring's or tomcat's cron?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cron, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

Does spring @Scheduled annotation use system's cron? (e.g. ubuntu cron) or spring's or tomcat's cron?

So can it work on any os? Or only where crontab exists on OS's level? What is under the hood there? (just a link to manual would be enough)

Answer (score 0):

It's using Unix cron. Please see documentation:
[Schedule annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#cron--)

Comment: What I see there: `A cron-like expression, extending the usual UN*X definition`, so only definition is from UN*X. Does implementation also use UN*X's ?